# Use PHP SoapServer in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, soap

I created a simple web-service and i want JQuery to be able to use the webservice. The webservice has no XML output or JSON output so i have no clue how to set that up with JQuery. The webservice works fine with PHP though. I have tried to change the header of page to xml and JSON:  `("Content-Type:text/xml");` and `header('Content-type: application/json');`
How do i set it up so JQuery can use the webservice?

Here is the full code:

**SoapServer.php**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');


function hello($name){
    return("hi" . $name);
}


$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri'=>'http://localhost/PHPWebService/hello'));
$server->addFunction("hello");
$server->handle();


?>
```

**SoapClient.php**

```
<?php 
try{
    $client = new SoapClient(null, array(
            'location'=>"http://localhost/PHPWebService/SoapServer.php",
            'uri' => "http://localhost/PHPWebService/hello"

    ));

    $result = $client->hello("Bob");
    echo($result);


}catch(SoapFault $ex){
    $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered this question i have solved this a other way. I used jakesankey's RESTful service instead of SOAP and created a JSON webservice this way. It works nice and is exactly what i was looking for.

Here is the link to the PHP RestServer: https://github.com/jakesankey/PHP-RestServer-Class